# When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project

Tags: twitter, oauth

When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.

I am having the problem, I am trying to GET /2/tweets with
-H Bearer {bearer token} and it’s giving me the error